# remove multiple sequenced files in R

Tags: r, file, removeall

i created multiple files named 1:100 + random letter to file:

```
for (i in 1:100){
  file.create( paste0(i , ".txt"), showWarnings=TRUE)

  # assign random LETTER to files
  AZ <- sample(LETTERS,1)
  cat(AZ,file = paste0(i,".txt"),append=TRUE)

  #rename files, and create new file with append of LETTERS
  name <- scan(file=paste0(i,".txt"), what="character")
  file.rename(paste0(i,".txt"), paste0(i, name,".txt"))
```

Now, i have a lot of files named like "1T, 2C, 3Y,..., 100A" and i want to remove all these files (not removing the rest that has in the directory) with file.remove function, how should i remove them without naming one by one? and all the directory named "exercicio03" with everything inside?

ps.: i have already tried

```
     file.remove(paste0(i,name,".txt"))
```

but is removing only the last file "100A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used a sample function, I think you can only be 100% sure that you remove only these files and no others, if you (did) save the values you became from that sample function. 
So your first part should have been:

```
 AZ<-NA
 for (i in 1:100){
 file.create( paste0(i , ".txt"), showWarnings=TRUE)

# assign random LETTER to files

 AZ[i] <- sample(LETTERS,1)
 cat(AZ[i],file = paste0(i,".txt"),append=TRUE)

#rename files, and create new file with append of LETTERS
 name <- scan(file=paste0(i,".txt"), what="character")
file.rename(paste0(i,".txt"), paste0(i, name,".txt"))
}
```

That way you can afterwards remove them all via this :

```
 for (i in 1:100){
  file.remove(paste0(i,AZ[i],".txt"))
 }
```

Comment: thanks!  i am also in a directory called "exercicio03", how can i remove it  with everything inside using the unlink function ?

Comment: unlink("exercicio03",recursive = TRUE) deletes directory and all in it

Answer (score 2):

You can easily remove only the files with names like `"1T.txt, 2C.txt, 3Y.txt, ..., 100A.txt"` with the following two lines of code:

```
remove.files <- list.files(".", pattern="^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]{1}\\.txt$")
do.call(file.remove,list(remove.files))
```

The script obtains all text files beginning with 1-3 digits followed by a letter in the current directory where you created them, and removes them.

Comment: The right procedure I reckon - `list.files` has a `pattern=` regex argument though, which would remove the need to create `all.files` and then chop it down to `remove.files`